# Correct pipe use

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am currently doing:

```
cat file1 file2 | sort -k1,1 > temp_file
command [options] -i temp_file > result_file
```

-i specifies the command input, in this case the file; I want a way to do this without explicitly specifying a temp_file.

`cat file1 file2 | sort -k1,1 | command [options] -i > result_file` fails,  complaining there's no file after the -i.

I also tried [xargs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) but that led to execution on every line of content instead of on the file.

Comment: How can i know if it does or not?

Comment: Does your system provide either `/dev/stdin` or `/proc/self/fd/0`? If so you might be able to use them as the filename after the `-i`, i.e. `sort -k1,1 file1 file2 | command [options] -i /dev/stdin` (no cat needed). A big limitation of piped input is that the program can not use the `lseek` or `seek` calls on it so the program must be written to process the data sequentially or else provide its own buffering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some applications understand `-` there to mean stdin (check its man page), so

```
sort... | cmd -i - > result.txt
```

Most systems have a `/dev/stdin` special file (same as `/dev/fd/0`), which when open behaves like duplicating stdin, so:

```
sort... | cmd -i /dev/stdin > result.txt
```

With some shells (ksh, zsh, bash), you can also write it:

```
cmd -i <(sort...) > result.txt
```

While that would work, that file is a pipe so is not *seekable*. Some `cmd`s may require a seekable file or a regular file and would fail if the file is a pipe. Then, you would have no other option than using a temporary file.

With `zsh`, you can use the `=(...)` form of [*process substitution*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Process-Substitution):

```
cmd -i =(sort ...) > result.txt
```

for `zsh` to create and populate and cleanup the temporary file automatically.

Same with `fish`, using [`psub`](https://fishshell.com/docs/2.4/commands.html#psub):

```
cmd -i (sort... | psub -f) > result.txt
```

With `bash`, still using a `/dev/fd/x` file but this time on a regular temporary file, deleted straight after it's opened for a more reliable clean-up:

```
tmp=$(mktemp) && {
  rm -f -- "$file" &&
    sort... >&3 3>&- 4<&- &&
    cmd -i /dev/fd/4 3>&-
} 3> "$tmp" 4< "$tmp"
```

Comment: The first solution worked, using the - it processed the as it was a file. I will try and remember the others as well. Great answer, thank you!